# Creating log backup file with .bak extension using serilog

Tags: serilog

I am using Serilog framework for logging in my application. The file size limit i have given is 2MB. So when the file reaches 2MB, new file is created with like app_001.log, existing app.log is a back up file. 
But what i want to do is when the file reaches 2MB, it should rename app.log to app.log.bak and write the new logs to newly created app.log file.

```
 _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                            .WriteTo.File(_filepath, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug, shared: true, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 2000000)
                             .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: What if you have more than backup files? how you will name them?

Comment: delete the existing back up file while renaming to "bak". at the end only one

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that derives from `FileLifecycleHooks` and override `OnFileOpened` and add some logic to check for the existence of `app_*.log` files and rename them to `app_*.bak`.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#extensibility